# Why arent the individual words printed?

Tags: python

I am writing a mini program and within my program there is a function which reads in a text file and returns the individual words from the sentence. However I am having trouble seeing the individual words printed even though I return them. I don't really get why unless I have a big problem with my whitespace. Can you please help? For your information I am only a beginner. The program asks the user for an input of a filename the program then reads the file in the function should then turn the fie into a list and find the individual words from the list and stores them in that list

```
file_input = input("enter a filename to read: ")
#unique_words = []
def file(user): 
    unique_words = []
    csv_file = open(user + ".txt","w")
    main_file = csv_file.readlines()
    csv_file.close()


    for i in main_list:
            if i not in unique_words:
                    unique_words.append(i)


    return unique_words

#display the results of the file being read in

print (file(file_input))
```

Sorry I am using notepad:

```
check to see if checking works
```

Comment: where is `individual_words` defined? are you after `unique_words.append`?

Comment: Thats probably what the `unique_words` is for but OP should **move that inside the function**.

Comment: Sorry changed the above however still not working

Comment: Are you sure that the result of your `for word in main_list:` loop is actually appending something into your `unique_words` list?

Comment: well I have used it in another function and seems to work perfectly fine

Comment: @pythonslittlehelper Add a `print(main_list)` just before the final for loop to make sure it is populated as you expect.

Comment: Why do you append `,`, join, and then split by `,`? Just convert the file to a list directly! Also, just do `unique_words = set(main_list)`

Comment: How would I do that? and where exactly would i put that

Comment: Also, can not reproduce. Using a test file with a few lines with comma-separated values, the program works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

it seems you only have one word for each line in your file.

```
def read_file(user): 
    with open(user + ".txt","r") as f:
        data = [ line.strip() for line in f.readlines() ]
    return list( set(data) )
```

--update---
if you have more than one word in each line and separated by space

```
def read_file(user): 
        with open(user + ".txt","r") as f:
            data = [ item.strip() for line in f.readlines() for item in line.split(' ')]
        return list( set(data) )
```

Comment: i would return the `list` of the `set` because that's what OP wants.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I would return a `set`, because a `list` implies some order, which the `set` will have destroyed.

Comment: Still does not print the individual words of a sentence

Comment: @pythonslittlehelper I think the issue is the structure of your txt. could you post some sample?

Comment: actually, you need `split()` not `strip()`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis agree. from po's code, I assume there is only one word for each line, but it seems not

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I can not reproduce you problem. Given a proper CSV input file <sup>1)</sup> such as

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
```

your program prints this, which apart from the last `''` seems fine:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', '']
```

However, you can *significantly* simplify your code.

- instead of appending a `,` to each line, and then joining by `""`, just join by `,` (this will also get rid of that last `''`)
- do the `strip` directly in `join`, using a generator expression

  ```
  main_string = ",".join(line.strip() for line in main_file)
  ```
- instead of `join` and then `split`, use a double-for-loop list comprehension:

  ```
  main_list = [word for line in csv_file for word in line.strip().split(",")]
  ```
- instead of doing all this by hand, use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

  ```
  main_list = [word for row in csv.reader(csv_file) for word in row]
  ```
- assuming that order is not important, use a `set` to remove duplicates:

  ```
  unique_words = set(main_list)
  ```
- and *if* order is important, you can (ab)use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

  ```
  unique_words = list(collections.OrderedDict((x, None) for x in main_list))
  ```
- use `with` to open and close the file

Putting it all together:

```
import csv
def read_file(user): 
    with open(user + ".txt") as csv_file:
        main_list = [word for row in csv.reader(csv_file) for word in row]
        unique_words = set(main_list)  # or OrderedDict, see above
        return unique_words
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> Update: The reason why it does not work on your "Example text..." file shown in your edit is because that is *not* a CSV file. CSV mean "comma separated values", but the words in that file a separated by spaces, so you will have to `split` by spaces instead of by commas:

```
def read_file(user): 
    with open(user + ".txt") as text_file:
        main_list = [word for line in text_file for word in line.strip().split()]
        return set(main_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a list of each word that occurs in the text, you are doing far too much work.  You want something like this:

```
unique_words = []
all_words = []
with open(file_name, 'r') as in_file:
  text_lines = in_file.readlines() # Read in all line from the file as a list.
for line in text_lines:
  all_words.extend(line.split()) # iterate through the list of lines, extending the list of all words to include the words in this line.
unique_words = list(set(all_words)) # reduce the list of all words to unique words.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using a `set` because it will only contain unique elements.

```
user_file = raw_input("enter a filename to read: ")

#function to read any file
def read_file(user):
    unique_words = set()
    csv_file = open(user + ".txt","r")
    main_file = csv_file.readlines()
    csv_file.close()

    for line in main_file:
        line = line.split(',')
        unique_words.update([x.strip() for x in line])

    return list(unique_words)

#display the results of the file being read in
print (read_file(user_file))
```

The output for a file with the contents:

```
Hello, world1
Hello, world2
```

is

```
['world2', 'world1', 'Hello']
```